# Where I am wrong to combine AND() and OR() within Excel formulae?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Where I am wrong to combine AND() and OR() within Excel formulae ?

`=If(OR(Sheet1!BC="A",Sheet1!BC="B" ) AND (Sheet1!CI<>"",Sheet1!CA=""),Sheet1!CI,Sheet1!CA)`

Whats wrong I am doing in here ? Please help

Comment: Are `BC`, `CI` and `CA` entire columns?

Comment: Are BC, CI, CA the names of cells?

Comment: Try this formulae whatever BC, CI, CA are: `=If(AND(OR(Sheet1!BC="A",Sheet1!BC="B" ),Sheet1!CI<>"",Sheet1!CA=""),Sheet1!CI,Sheet1!CA)`

Comment: @bzimor Thank you , It accepts the formula . But I am not getting any output. `Sheet1!CA` and `Sheet1!CI` is a date , Do I have to use any date formula or it will work as it is ?

Comment: @bizmor Also I reduced the formula to `=IF(AND( Sheet1!BC<>"", Sheet1!CI<>"", Sheet1!CA=""),Sheet1!CI,Sheet1!CA)` but still it shows Name error

Comment: As @swmcdonnell already said in his answer, you need to reference cells, not entire columns (you need a row number next to column letter)

Comment: Okay I have done it correct now . Thanks all `=IF(AND( Sheet1!BC2<>"", Sheet1!CI2<>"", Sheet1!CA2=""),Sheet1!CI2,Sheet1!CA2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

1) `AND()` is a function that works the same as `OR()`:

```
=IF(AND(a1=2, b1=3, c1=6), "true", "false")
```

2) Here's an example of combining `AND()` and `OR()` in a single equation:

```
=IF(AND(OR(a1=1, b1=2), OR(a2=9, b2=10)), "true", "false")
```

That reads ***If (a1=1 or b1=2) and (a2=9 or b2=10)***

3) You're only referencing column names in your formula, not cell names. If you want to compare the value for a cell, you need to include the row number. So `BC` needs to be `BC#` (where # is the correct row), `CI` needs to be `CI#`, `CA` needs to be `CA#`

4) What you have after the `AND()` in your example doesn't make any sense.

```
(Sheet1!CI<>"",Sheet1!CA=""),Sheet1!CI,Sheet1!CA)
```

Did you mean to put an `OR()`  around the first two? What are the second two `CI` and `CA` for?

I tried to rewrite your equation, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.